# change gradient colour at end of ListView

Tags: android

On the Google Nexus S, when one tries to drag past the end of a ListView, a yellow gradient appears, and its size is determined by the distance dragged. How does one change the colour of this gradient? I cannot see anything obvious.

It is **not** cacheColorHint.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be hard-coded in the ScrollView implementation. Have a look at [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java;;hb=HEAD), the `setOverScrollMode()` method on line 1389 (the exact line number may change if someone updates the source):

```
@Override
 public void setOverScrollMode(int mode) {
     if (mode != OVER_SCROLL_NEVER) {
         if (mEdgeGlowTop == null) {
             final Resources res = getContext().getResources();
             final Drawable edge = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.overscroll_edge);
             final Drawable glow = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.overscroll_glow);
             mEdgeGlowTop = new EdgeGlow(edge, glow);
             mEdgeGlowBottom = new EdgeGlow(edge, glow);
         }
     } else {
         mEdgeGlowTop = null;
         mEdgeGlowBottom = null;
     }
     super.setOverScrollMode(mode);
 }
```

The only way that I can see is to define your own ScrollView implementation, override `setOverScrollMode()` to use your own drawables, and then implent your own `ListView` which will use your ScrollView implementation instead of the standard one.

Comment: What is EdgeGlow? Where can I find this class?